# How to contain text inside div when resized in css flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If I use use table and table cell, I can achieve it like this:

```css
    #wrap {
        /* Your styling. */
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid black;
        z-index: 999999;
        right: 0;
        height: 60%;
        text-align: center;
    
        /* Solution part I. */
        display: table;
    }
    
    /* Solution part II. */
    #inside {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

```html
 <div id=wrap>
      <div id=inside>
        Content, content, content.
      </div> 
    </div>
```

But How do I achieve the same in css Flex box?

I have my code like this for flex:

```css
.dflex{
   display: flex;
}

.orange{
   background: #F97434;
}
    
.section2 {
    height: 874px;
    min-height: 34em;
    height: 1056px;
    background: #424242;
}

.block{
    padding: 0% 20%;
}

.block-wrap1, .block-wrap2{
    /*height: 37%;*/
    height: 323px;
    width: 40.8%;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    padding: 1em;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    margin: auto 0 1.5em 2em;
}

.section2 .block-content{
    padding: 0 1em;
    align-self: center;
}

.block-content{
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 1.6em;
}
```

```html
<section class="section2 cscroll">

<div class="block dflex">
    <div class="block-wrap1 orange dflex"><div class="block-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</div> </div>
    <div class="block-wrap1 orange dflex"><div class="block-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</div> </div>
</div>

<div class="block dflex">
    <div class="block-wrap2 orange dflex"><div class="block-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</div> </div>
    <div class="block-wrap2 orange dflex"><div class="block-content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's</div> </div>
</div>

</section>
```

As the the two blocks are on two rows with `display:flex` used twice, the `stretch` is equal for all the blocks. How do I fix this?

Comment: link doesn't work, make a snippet instead

Comment: @A.Lau created snippet

Comment: Not quite clear what you want. The contents are different. Do you just want the text to be a single line?

Comment: @A.Lau The text should always remaining inside the div when the div is resized to large or small

Comment: @A.Lau Run the second snippet and you can see the text is overflowing outside the orange box

Comment: Well... you don't actually have a flexbox... maybe check your code first? Probably css

Comment: Why do you use fixed height("323px")?

Comment: @Marian07 Because all the blocks should be of same height

Comment: @Marian07 If I don't use ` height("323px")` then the first two blocks are of different height and the following two blocks will have different height

Comment: @kittu, HTML structure approach problem. Solution underway.

Comment: @Marian07 Okie :)

Comment: All blocks should be displayed on a single row? Because in flex layout, a block can influence it's siblings, with stretch, as @j-printemps pointed. Example: https://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/gpard

Comment: @Marian07 That is where the problem is. I need the blocks on two rows. If I use `display:flex` twice for each row then strech(height) won't be the same for all blocks

Comment: Probably, you will need Javascript and DOM to calculate the highest row and update the others according to it.
Or, with CSS, on each block, use min-height and use overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

If you have multiple blocks, with different height, I suggest you use `strech` instead of having a fixed height. Like in the example below:

```css
.dflex{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
}

.section2 {
    min-height: 34em;
}


.block{
    padding: 0% 20%;
}

.block-wrap1{
    //flex: 0 0 100%;
    flex: 1 1 0px;
    min-width: initial;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    padding: 1em;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    border: 1px solid black;
    word-break: break-all;
}

.section2 .block-content{
    padding: 0 1em;
    align-self: center;
}

.block-content{
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="section2">
    <div class="block dflex">
        <div class="block-wrap1">
            <p class="block-content">Isn’t the pharmaceutical industry just out to make money?</p> 
        </div>
        
         <div class="block-wrap1">
            <p class="block-content">Isn’t the pharmaceutical.</p> 
        </div>
        
         <div class="block-wrap1">
            <p class="block-content">Isn’t the pharmaceutical industry.</p> 
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you. So I shouldn't let it grow or shrink and have basis to 100%?

Comment: First, only the container needs `display: flex;`, the content doesn't. Then, it depends on the kind of rendering you need. I added `justify-content: center;` to centered the content. You can remove `max-width: 40.8%;`. And you need to shrink it according to the content, you can use `flex: 0 0 auto;`. And also, your text goes out of the div if the word is longer than you container, so you can use `word-break: break-all;`.

Comment: I have 4 blocks like that. I need to stretch all of them to same height

Comment: If I use `height:37%` the text overflows out of div. Check this site once: https://www.vaccinestoday.eu/ They have apparently used tables and table-cells for this. Also If I use word-wrap like you suggested, it text breaks at corners

Comment: @kittu, post your whole example.

Comment: @Marian07 Okay. In a min